# Copying likes from an URL to a newly created fanpage linked to that URL

Tags: url, facebook-like, share, facebook-page

I've a site and each article page with its unique URL can be "liked".

Now I've setup fanpages for the most important articles, and I'd like the fanpages to share the likes with the associated article urls.

eg: article located at www.example.com/hello-world has 1000 likes. I create a fanpage facebook.com/pages/Hello-World "linked" (?) to www.example.com/hello-world and automatically starts at 1000 likes.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to migrate fans from Open Graph pages to regular Pages on facebook.com, but you can use the admin page for the Open Graph page to post updates to the fans of the Open Graph page, there should be an 'admin' link visible to you when you're looking at your site while logged in as the admin of the app you linked to the URL (you can also specify a user id directly)

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive reply.